# Tabs ready event not firing when calling window.open on Firefox 24

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have developed an add-on using the Firefox Add-on SDK 1.14.

This add-on listens to tabs.ready events to perform an action.

Starting on Firefox 24, the tabs.ready event is no longer fired when a page is loaded by means of a window.open call.

Sample add-on code:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('ready', function(tab){console.log(tab.url)});
```

Sample page code:

```
window.open(
    'http://stackoverflow.com', 
    '', 
    'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,status=yes,location=yes'
    );
```

Am I missing something or the Add-on SDK is not behaving correctly?

Comment: This isn't the SDK bug tracker. This is: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK&component=General

Comment: That is the thing: I don't know if it is a bug or a change in the SDK behaviour. This is why I am asking. I have searched the SDK bug to no avail.

Comment: This is working for me in FF 24 and 27, both with using the internal `require('sdk/windows').browserWindows.open(url)`, or using `window.open` manually in an open existing page. Is there some other missing information?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @jsantell. Unfortunately there isn't any additional information... I've checked again, using a fresh install on a different environment, FF 24, Addon-SDK 1.14 just downloaded, Python 2.7.5 and a test add-on containing only `var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('ready', function(tab){console.log(tab.url)});`. Same results.

Comment: I'm more interested in what's causing this to open a new tab. Is the `window.open` on the page you're landing on? Is it making a new tab in the same window? Do you get a popup notification asking if it's okay to allow popups from this domain? Is it a user-triggered window.open?

Comment: I open a page on a normal tab of a normal FF window: the add-on works as expected. This page contains a button which fires the `window.open` call specified on my original question. This call opens a new window with no tabs and no popup notifications / warnings. The tabs.ready event doesn't get fired for this newly opened window.